# Jest mock async function from default import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I'm trying to mock an async function that is exported as a default export but all I get is **TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**

What I'm trying to mock is **config.js**:

```
const configureEnvironment = async (nativeConfig) => {
    return { await whatever() }
}
```

The file I'm testing is **Scene.js**:

```
import configureEnvironment from './config';

class Scene extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        nativeConfig = {};
        configureEnfironment(nativeConfig).then((config) => {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

And my test file is **Scene.test.js**:

```
let getScene = null;
const configureEnvironmentMock = jest.fn();

describe('Scene', () => {
    jest.mock('./config', () => configureEnvironmentMock);

    const Scene = require('./Scene').default;

    getScene = (previousState) => {
        return shallow(
            <Scene prevState={previousState}>
                <Fragment />
            </Scene>,
        );
    };

    it('calls configureEnvironment with the nativeConfig', async () => {
        expect.assertions(1);
        const nativeConfig = {};

        getScene(nativeConfig);

        expect(configureEnvironmentMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(nativeConfig);
    });
});
```

However, the result of running the test is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

I understand the issue is on the way I mock configureEnvironment but I cannot get it working.

I also tried to mock the function like:

```
jest.mock('./config', () => {
    return {
        default: configureEnvironmentMock,
    };
});
```

But it results on:

```
TypeError: (0 , _config2.default) is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clean and simple way to mock the default export of a module is to use [`jest.spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) in combination with functions like [`mockImplementation`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn).

---

Here is a working example based on the code snippets above:

config.js

```jsx
const whatever = async () => 'result';

const configureEnvironment = async (nativeConfig) => await whatever();

export default configureEnvironment;
```

---

Scene.js

```jsx
import * as React from 'react';
import configureEnvironment from './config';

export class Scene extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    configureEnvironment(props.prevState).then((config) => {
      // Do stuff
    });
  }
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

---

Scene.test.js

```jsx
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import { Scene } from './Scene';
import * as config from './config';

describe('Scene', () => {

  const mock = jest.spyOn(config, 'default'); // spy on the default export of config
  mock.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve('config')); // replace the implementation

  const getScene = (previousState) => {
    return shallow(
      <Scene prevState={previousState}>
        <Fragment />
      </Scene>,
    );
  };

  it('calls configureEnvironment with the nativeConfig', async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    const nativeConfig = {};

    getScene(nativeConfig);

    expect(mock).lastCalledWith(nativeConfig);  // SUCCESS
  });
});
```

Comment: Works perfect. The key thing for me was the ability to import as `import * as config from './config';` allowing then to spy on the default export.

Comment: I get 'Cannot spy the default property because it is not a function; object given instead'. I guess this only works if the export is a function

Comment: @Marc yes, this approach is for when the default export is a function

Comment: how to use this for named exports?

Answer (score 0):

You can mock anything with jest, like this

`jest.mock('@material-ui/core/withWidth', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  isWidthUp: jest.fn((a, b) => true),
  default: jest.fn(fn => fn => fn)
}))`

Comment: And how do you restore it after this test?